# Update all data in MongoDB or replace MongoDB instance

Tags: mongodb, google-bigquery

MongoDB contains data ready for client-side apps. The raw data being stored in Google BigQuery (GBQ). Each day a lot of new data being added into GBQ and once a day pretty much everything in MongoDB needs to be updated according to the most recent data in GBQ. All outdated (not updated) records must be deleted.

What is the right way to handle MongoDB update with close to 0 downtime?

1. Among the crazy solutions: may be i should have two instances of MongoDB, one is in production, another is being updated. Once the second db updated, i'll run Google Kubernetes Engine deploy with changed configs, so all clients will be smoothly moved from previous data to the updated one without messing up with partially updated data and without downtime. Though, i have never heard about such solutions, so i'm not sure if this is the right one.
2. Another solution is to have two versions of each collection under a single instance of MongoDB. Once collection is updated, server switches to that collection.

Comment: Would there be a way to recognize what data is outdated and what not? Or is everything outdated at the end of the day?

Comment: do the clients point to a domain name? you could run two mongoDB instances and then just update the ip behind the domain when an update is completed

Comment: just to know the context better: why do you use mongodb and not a regular rdbms in your case?

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd solution seems a good option, if you know the trigger for the update, you can have minimum downtime by creating a new collection (named by date or a unique serial maybe) and update your code accordingly.

I had some good experience doing this for a fashion website sometime back, where we scraped data (using scrapinghub) and imported them into mongodb (collections stored by date) and used accordingly. So our scraping ran early morning (5-6AM) and when our editors/curators came in the office, they would start using the current dated collection (via the Web Interface of course :) )